# How can I automate long running test cases with VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

The software I worked on has both unit tests and system tests. System tests can take minutes to run, they take input values and we validate the results against expected output. There are hundreds of system tests. The software must be built (done this) and tested on both windows and Linux. 
How can I automate testing with VSTS? I'd like to avoid doing this at build stage, because it would slow the builds down. I can't see how to automate this in the Test stage. Do I need additional extensions to do this? Everything seems so geared up for web development, e.g. selenium tests, how do we run automated tests for good old binary programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/what-is-release-management?view=vsts) to deploy your application to a test environment and then [run your tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/set-up-continuous-test-environments-builds?view=vsts) as a part of your Release Definition. You can then choose to run tests in parallel to make sure that your system tests don't take days to run.

On a side note, having so many system tests is a code smell. I would suggest looking into building as many fast running unit tests as possible and only using system tests when absolutely necessary.